# Firebase, how to limit retrive requests from a specific Dataset (Realtime-Database)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am looking for a way to trigger an action when a specific dataset was retrieved **`x`** times. Unfortunately, Cloud functions for firebase doesn't have a trigger like `onRetrive()`.

For example, my Firebase Realtime-Database looks like this:

- rootDB

  - info001

    - limit: "35"
    - message: "a message, that can be retrived 35 times"
  - info002

    - limit: "10"
    - message: "another message, that can be retrieved 10 times"

After the limit is reached I want to remove (or move the dataset to another path).

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to tackle the problem?

Comment: "Unfortunately Cloud functions for firebase doesnt have a trigger like onRetrive()." -> If you are ready to use Cloud Functions, you could use them to read the data in your Realtime Database (and block read access from the clients SDK through security rules). Then it would be quite easy to maintain a counter for each node and trigger the desired action when the limit is reached. Be sure to read this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c) from Doug Stevenson before deciding to go with this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to know for sure if something was read from the database would be to force the client through a backend you control.  The backend would record the database read, then take further actions from there.  You can use Cloud Functions for this by implementing an HTTP or callable function that can be invoked from the client.